# zoom h4n multi track recording

Tags: zoom-h4n, editing, files, multichannel

The zoom h4n is a brilliant set recorder! Now after I have recorded a session using all the channels (the xlr inputs and onboard mics) when I take the SD card or usb and put into in a computer will there be files for each channel's recordings?

Answer (score 3):

There will be a pair of stereo files per recording in the 4ch folder, named appropriately.

Comment: ahaha u feel kinda silly cos i was walking last night and I had a eureka momentthank you so much dave 